# Miniconda3/envs/foo/ does not contain python interpreter which is needed for linking with pycharm; where else?

Tags: python, pycharm, miniconda

I want to link pycharm to my custom python environment called "tensorflow"
To do so I installed Miniconda3 on a windows 10 machine, created the environment  and installed some packages there.
In my command prompt I can ofcourse activate the environment and see the packages installed with pip list.

Now I want to link this environment to pycharm, and for this I need the python interpreter and its location.
Having googled this is supposed to be in

```
C:\Users\foo\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\bin\
```

In my case however the folder is empty besides .nonadmin file and conda-meta map which also dont include an interpreter.

When I execute a python file that tells me the interpreter location from command prompt with the tensorflow interpreter it tells me the base interpreter is used.

```
C:\Users\foo\Miniconda3\python.exe
```

This seems wrong, and linking pycharm to this interpreter does not give me the right interpreter as the needed packages are not installed there.

I tried creating another environment to see if the same would happen, again an almost empty directory with no python interpreter there for me to link to.

How can I link my Tensorflow environment to pycharm?

Comment: How do you create your environment? Do you specify the python version you need when you create it? `conda create -n yourenvname python=x.x`

Comment: I use `conda create -n tensorflow`
I believe that should results in the source python used: 3.6, I think that should result in the same as when I'm specifying it explicitly. Regardless I'll try to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I'll be damned. Specifying the python version explicitly fixed it, the folder is now filled with the interpreter and more. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked!